# my crontab doesn't send mails anymore

Tags: email, cron

Before saturday, mailing after crontab executions were working but from now on, it doesn't work at all, but the config didn't changed. Operating system : Debian 7.5
I tried using PHP the mail function, it works, so my postfix server works.
Any idea?

EDIT : 
My mail log :

```
Jul 29 12:45:45 vps62224 postfix/smtpd[4248]: connect from unknown[unknown]
Jul 29 12:45:45 vps62224 postfix/smtpd[4248]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[unknown]
Jul 29 12:45:45 vps62224 postfix/smtpd[4248]: disconnect from unknown[unknown]
Jul 29 12:45:52 vps62224 postfix/pickup[4039]: 65089275EC57: uid=0 from=<user>
Jul 29 12:45:52 vps62224 postfix/cleanup[4231]: 65089275EC57: message-id=<20140729104552.65089275EC57@vps62224.ovh.net>
Jul 29 12:45:52 vps62224 postfix/qmgr[2237]: 65089275EC57: from=<user@vps62224.ovh.net>, size=4949, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 29 12:46:28 vps62224 postfix/smtp[4233]: CF73D275EC53: to=<flux@reinova.fr>, relay=mx1.ovh.net[213.186.33.29]:25, delay=90, delays=0.22/0.01/60/30, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx1.ovh.net[213.186.33.29] said: 550 sorry, user over quota (#5.1.1) (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Jul 29 12:46:28 vps62224 postfix/smtp[4233]: CF73D275EC53: lost connection with mx1.ovh.net[213.186.33.29] while sending DATA command
Jul 29 12:46:28 vps62224 postfix/cleanup[4231]: 0D9DF275EC58: message-id=<20140729104628.0D9DF275EC58@vps62224.ovh.net>
Jul 29 12:46:28 vps62224 postfix/qmgr[2237]: 0D9DF275EC58: from=<>, size=2603, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 29 12:46:28 vps62224 postfix/bounce[4255]: CF73D275EC53: sender non-delivery notification: 0D9DF275EC58
Jul 29 12:46:28 vps62224 postfix/qmgr[2237]: CF73D275EC53: removed
Jul 29 12:46:28 vps62224 postfix/local[4257]: 0D9DF275EC58: to=<user@vps62224.ovh.net>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

Comment: What's in your mail logs?

Comment: Cosmic Rays - how can anyone answer your question ? What changes have been made, are there any relevant messages in your logs, which OS/Distro are you using? ...

Comment: i'm using a debian 7.5. I haven't made any changes, I didn't work on these days, so nobody has change nothing on the server

Comment: Everything is in your logs, try reading 'em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
host mx1.ovh.net[213.186.33.29] said: 550 sorry, user over quota (#5.1.1) (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

over quota ? Recipient mailbox seems full. Either clean the mailbox or add more space.

Comment: Sorry, that's stupid. I just started to be server administrator....